# PanInquiryBackEnd Authentication Failure

Tags: asp.net, certificate

Pan Inquiry BackEnd  api use then same error occurs have u any other method for pan card api

```
enter code here
   System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    postData.Append("data=" + dataReg);
    postData.Append("signature=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sigi));
```